# Why is my images not showing up to the GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist

I can't get my images to display on my GridView.

This is how i declare my array list

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrImages = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is in my onCreate

```
    int i = 0;
    for (Words wd : words)
    {

        String log = "Id: " + wd.getId() + " ,Name: " + wd.getName();
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("wordList : ", log);

        arrImages.add( this.getResources().getIdentifier(wd.getName(), "drawable", this.getPackageName()));

        i++;
    }

    //gridView
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    adapter = new MyGridViewAdapter(this, arrImages);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

This is in my BaseAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;
    LinearLayout outerLayout;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //recycling logic
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_images,null);

    }

    imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivGrid_images);

    imageView.setImageResource(images.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: you just need extra eyes and you will get it :)

Comment: what's getCount returning ?

Comment: @Elltz lend me your eyes :(

Comment: @Blackbelt getCount return 0? o.o

Comment: you should read the documentation

Comment: @Blackbelt  owhh return images.size();??? thankss although you marked duplicated lolol thankss ^_^

Comment: Thankss @Elltz too :D